# bonjour between iphone and mac/windows

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any sample that I can use to learn how to transfer text between iPhone and a computer (mac/pc) using bonjour?

Answer (score 2):

We used AsynchSocket. It was pretty easy to incorporate + good examples of client & server side. [AsynchSocket usage](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxix-message)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [BLIP protocol](http://bitbucket.org/snej/mynetwork/wiki/BLIP/Protocol).  It is a fairly good drop in library that allows you to send messages back and forth.

Comment: thanks I have tried that one and it's not as problem free as the author would love to offer. Thx though!

Comment: I don't remember him claiming it to be problem free but I have been using it in ZSync for quite a while now and it is pretty impressive and easy to implement.